# why I have an Access error on Angular2 api Request?

Tags: angular, api, post, request

I am working on an Angular project. I have a post request to an api but when I run this I get the following access error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://150.140.143.213:8085/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My service is :

```
 addnik(park: any): Observable<any>{

            const httpOptions = {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type':  'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
              }),
            };
            return this.httpclient.post<any>("http://150.140.143.213:8085/",park,
              httpOptions, );

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, it should be returned by the API http://150.140.143.213:8085/ otherwise it will not work.